# Add marginal density plot based on subset of plotted data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line plot `p` generated from a long/melted dataframe `DF`.

I would now like to add a marginal density plot along the y axis to show the distribution of `score` at `t5`. I have just come across `ggExtra::ggMarginal`, but the tutorials I've found only seem to work with scatter plots and not with subsets of the main plot's data.

---

Here's the structure of `DF`:

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   600 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 6 levels "t0","t1","t2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : num  0.737 0.33 0.526 0.737 0.357 ...
```

And here's my line plot `p`:

[image]

---

I tried this...

```
# the code that produces the line plot above
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = ID, group = ID))+
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  ylim(0, 1) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Score", color = "ID", subtitle = "")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

#trying to add marginal density plot based on subsetted t5 scores
p <- ggMarginal(p, data = DF[which(DF$variable == "t5"),], x = value, type = "density")
```

But it throws this error: `Error: No geom_point layer was found in your scatter plot`

Does `ggMarginal` only work with scatter plots? How might I add a marginal density plot of `score` at `t5` to the right side y axis?

Comment: According to help `ggMarginal` needs a scatterplot, so I think it really needs a `geom_point` layer. As a dirty hack, maybe you can make the points invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question following @ricoderks comment.

It seems the solution is to just plot an invisible scatter plot. Here's the code that worked:

```
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = ID, group = ID))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = DF[which(DF$variable == "t5"),], alpha = 0)+
  theme_bw() +
  ylim(0, 1) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Score", color = "ID", subtitle = "")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
p <- ggMarginal(p, type = "density", margins = "y", size = 6, color = "steelblue4")
```

[image]